# Why is "Add feature" of the GPS Information tool inactive for some of my PostGIS layers?

Tags: qgis, postgis, gps, qgis-2

I cannot find any info on limitations/requirements of "GPS Information" tool for QGIS (2.2.0) against data layers.

For some layers I'm able to collect data for others button "Add feature" is inactive (despite layer is read/write and in an edit mode). My goal is to collect features directly to existing PostGIS layers.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this twice with QGIS 2.2.0, and both times, even though the layer was editable, it would not allow GPS data to be added.

I moved the offending layer to the top of the list, toggled editing on and off for that layer, then made another layer editable (a junk shot layer for troubleshooting).
I recorded some data in the junk shot layer.

I then made the layer I wanted to add data to editable, clicked on the layer to highlight it, then recorded the point data. It seemed to work after doing all of that.
Once again, I moved that layer to the top of the layer list.

A lot of jumping around to get it to work though.

This probably is not much help, but it worked for me.

With some minor improvements to the interface for the GPS information window, and the ability to refer to a feature table, (the dreaded data dictionary, or attribute table) QGIS would make a very nice mapping, and even surveying package.